# Quadratic equation modulo primes

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I am doing a number theory course and our assignment is asking us to find the solutions to two quadratic equations mod some prime $p$.
$$x^2 + bx +c \equiv 0\ mod\ p_1 $$
$$x^2 + bx +c \equiv 0\ mod\ p_2 $$

So we must use Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the 4 possible roots of x. In class, the only thing we've been shown how to do is find a specific version of the square root of a number, primarily:

Given $n$, a prime number that satisfies the equation $n\ \%\ 4 = 3$, then we know that $\sqrt{x} = \pm x^{\frac{n+1}{4}}$. Both of the above primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ do satisfy this, by the way.

I have searched questions online, and this seems like the closest way that I should be solving something in the quadratic form where we are using a modulo of p:
[quadratic equation modulo some number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024374/quadratic-equation-modulo-some-number)

Once it is reduced to $\sqrt{x} \equiv D$ mod $n$ then I can use the above formula.

However, I am concerned since we were not taught the method in the link above and it doesn't seem intuitive to me that we find $\sqrt{x} \equiv D$ mod $n$ , the only thing we were shown was how to obtain general square roots mod $n$. Is the method in the link the best way to solve these equations, or are there other methods - given the parameters?

**Note:** I have not given the actual question since it is an assignment question.

Thanks for your time

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. How to compute modular square roots? How to solve modular quadratics? How to use CRT to combine the roots? All of these have been asked and answered many times here.

Comment: I was pretty clear in the first sentence, "I am trying to find the solutions to two quadratic equations mod some prime p ..." "... find the 4 possible roots of x". I also made it clear that I have searched online and not sure how to find the answer given the tools I have been given, also given in the post.  Your comment is unhelpful and not true.